# Matrices and converting Float4 to Vector3

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine

I have a basic understanding of matrices and have done some quick reading into this, simple question really but if i was to convert a Vector3 into a Float4 would it be as simple as:

Vector3(x,y,z) = Float4(x,y,z,0)

If not can anyone point me towards further reading on how this conversion could be done etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about manual conversion; implicit conversion has been in the API forever.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Vector4-operator_Vector4.html

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Vector4-operator_Vector3.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can't find anything about the Float4 class (http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Float4). But, in theory, my solution would be the following:

```
Vector3 v3(1,2,3);
Float4 f4(4,5,6,0);

v3.x = f4.x;
v3.y = f4.y;
v3.z = f4.z;
```